# something wrong with my loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a box disappear and reappear alternatively by using the loop. The problem is that the box does not appear at all though the loop runs until i=10. Can someone explain this?

```
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(document.getElementById("box").style.display=="none"){
            document.getElementById("box").style.display="block";}
        else{
            document.getElementById("box").style.display="none";
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
```

Comment: JS runs in the same thread that the browser users to paint the page. All of your code finishes running before the page updates. Look into using `setTimeout()` of `setInterval()` instead of a for loop.

Comment: Please give your question a title that lets people know what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest explanation is that the loop iteration finishes before the rendering takes place, and you only get the end result.

See this modified version of your code, it's kind of forcing the drawing by using timeouts:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(toggle, i * 100);
}

function toggle() {
  if (document.getElementById("box").style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Why when I remove i in i*100, the box stands still?

Comment: Because you're telling the timeout to execute its function right away and it's the same as your original code.

Comment: So this is the difference between java and javascript? I just considered i*100 as away to make the timeout various. I test with 10 second but the result is the same. So as you said, it is necessary to involve i in the timeout

Comment: That code generates 10 timeouts, right away. They execute all in their own time. If you drop `i`, you'd generate 10 timeouts that would execute at the same time (whether 10 seconds from now or just 1 second, it doesn't matter, the point is that they'd execute at the same time). So that's the problem, you need spread those timeouts a bit, and that's why used `i`. There are tons of other ways to do it, but I thought this would be enough to help you understand what's going on inside the loop and why you only see the end result.

Comment: PMH - reading [some doco about JS timers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers) may help. Or [John Resig's Timers article](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you loop simply with (while, for, etc ...) it will run in a clock-cicle(nano-seconds, or milli-seconds) ...

For the computer, your box is appearing and disappearing. But not for humans, simply because it's too fast.

I suggest you to try you algorithm with some Javascript animations, like this one

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadein.asp